# DynamoDB Support for JSON Documents

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

AWS DynamoDB recently released support for JSON documents per: http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/

Questions:

1) How can I use this if I am making a request directly to the service?  Do I just set the M value to the entire json object?

2) Can indexes be included in the JSON document? Will DynamoDB be able to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the link you included in your question, the support for JSON is built into many of the AWS SDKs rather than being entirely implemented in DynamoDB. Using DynamoDB's new `Map` and `List` types for example, a JSON structure is mapped to DynamoDB types and structures in a predictable way. So, no, you would not set an `M` value to the entire JSON object (unless that's the final structure you wanted).

Indexes continue to be available using the standard access patterns as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) for example.

You would need to use one of the SDKs or provide your own service layer to map a JSON document to a DynamoDB item.

Currently (*November 2014*), the AWS-SDK for JavaScript (which includes NodeJS) does not have built-in support for JSON data. However, it is available through an AWS-Labs project [here](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk).  You'll see in [that](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk/blob/master/lib/dynamodb-doc.js) code that the document client code attaches to an event so that all of the data can be formatted (from JSON to native DynamoDB):

```
request.on("extractData", f.formatOutput);
```

Where `f` is an instance of their [`DynamoDBFormatter`](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk/blob/master/lib/formatter.js).

Comment: I don't believe the article is very clear unfortunately. It only references a handful of SDKs but not actually how JSON support is implemented. This isn't helpful at all if you are using a different SDK. Unfortunately I use Node and thus I guess this isn't supported.
Can you provide an example of the JSON doc and the corresponding request the SDK creates to the DynamoDB service? I believe it should be "Item": {
        "key": {
            "S": "keyValStr"
        },
        "document":
             "M": { "attr": "val",
                    "subObj": {}
                    "subArray: [1] }

Comment: Support for the JSON documents was added to the JavaScript SDK: http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/SDK/JavaScript/1691866671551861.

Comment: Awesome, the code in the AWS-Labs shows me how I can support JSON by converting into the AWS DynamoDb format. I see the release notes you mention above stating JSON support but I am not see it in any reference documents. Can you provide a snippet of the code to use this functionality? Are they just stating you can do what the AWS Labs projects does but don't have built in support?

Comment: My impression is that the labs project represents what will be present in the official SDK. It's just not done yet. The other SDKs apparently were finished first.

Answer (score 1):

The awslabs project looks really promising and full featured, but it's not currently published to npm (2014 December).

**[node-dynamodb](https://github.com/totemstech/node-dynamodb)**

That looks really good, wish I had found it sooner.

Before I wrote a more simple JSON => DynamoDb conversion module.

**[dynamodb-marshaler](https://github.com/CascadeEnergy/dynamoDb-marshaler)**