# What does the createTable for DynamoDB in Java with a column containing a JSON value?

Tags: java, json, scala, amazon-dynamodb, create-table

I am attempting to use the Java/JSON examples located at [this web page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-update-json-and-more/) (which describes the introduction of JSON as a native type to DynamoDB). And while I understand the examples presented on the page, there is no place on the page showing how to go about defining the "people" table itself in Java.

I did find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697538/dynamodb-support-for-json-documents) talking in the area. However, it appears to have been asked and answered PRIOR to the article above introducing the "official" version of the new API. And even reviewing the article didn't give me enough clues to figure it out myself.

BTW, I am NOT able to use the "AWS Toolkit for Eclipse" as must use the results of this in IntelliJ+Scala-Plugin using SBT.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, that blog post should probably show the schema definition. Examining the examples shows that the table has a [primary key type of hash](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.PrimaryKey) with attribute name `person_id` with a datatype of [`Number`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.DataTypes). Are you asking how you create a table using the Document model API?

Comment: Given he is using a "DynamoDB" class, I would love for it to be shown using this particular class. However, if that doesn't work, then something similar to what is provided at this link would be nice: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AppendixSampleDataCodeJava.html

Comment: BTW, I just realized that the document column may not have to be defined in the createTable code. Not sure. It would be helpful if there was a full example from createTable through putting an item into the table and then removing it where a non primary key attribute is actually a JSON document.

Comment: The `"document"` attribute would not be a "column" in DynamoDB. All of the attributes and their types (besides the schema definition for the table and indexes) do not have to be defined, and can be added/deleted/updated at any time. "`document`" for one item can be a JSON blob, while for another item is could be a String.